# Is there any function that does a linear interpolation using lists?

Tags: numerics, interpolation

Is there any function that does a linear interpolation using lists?

Something where I could report a list with a number of any, as below:

```
data = {{161 + 15, 0}, {x1, 525 - 18}, {103.4, 525}}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  176 & 0 \\
>  \text{x1} & 507 \\
>  103.4 & 525 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Some function that actually does the following interpolation procedure:

```
x1=data[[1,1]]+((data[[3,1]]-data[[1,1]])/(data[[3,2]]-data[[1,2]]))*data[[2,2]]
```

> 105.889

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As our friend @Shadowray said in the comments

```
data = {{161 + 15, 0}, {x1, 525 - 18}, {103.4, 525}};

Rescale[
 data[[2, 2]], {data[[1, 2]], data[[3, 2]]}, {data[[1, 1]], 
  data[[3, 1]]}]
```

> 105.889

The image below presents the idea of [`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good reply, but it appears to be limited to short lists with small dimension. Problems with coding and performance may exist using larger lists or higher dimensions. For instance, I frequently need  need to get f[{x,y,z..}] where {x,y,z} is interpolated interpolated values from 100 entries. In that case you might try different (Rescale) or (Interpolation) code. Of course there are many quadratic lookups (ie, binary search) that work for statistically random, large lists. I didn't offer a new code because your answer satisfies the original question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/120993)